# Two columns layout; 3rd sibling element without use of margin

Tags: html, css

I am creating two columns layout. The left column (header) is sticky/fixed, whereas the right column is static. HTML has 3 sibling elements (`header`, `div.content-column`, `footer`). The footer is placed below `.content-column`.

I am looking for a solution (without nesting `.content-column` with `footer`) and NOT to use `margin-left` for the footer to be next to the header. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

```css
body, ul {margin:0;}

header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content-column {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size:3rem;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 40vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 40vw;
}
.content-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 60vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

footer {
  margin-left: 40vw;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
<a href="#">logo</a>
<span>logo subtitle</span>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="content-column">
  <main>
    <article>
Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia. Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia.
Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia.…
Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia.…
    </article>
  </main>
</div>
<footer>
2023
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Grid to accomplish the layout you want without calculating the margin as you said. As an example, like so:

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content-column {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30vw 1fr;
  }

  header {
    height: 100vh;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

  footer {
    grid-column: 2/-1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#">logo</a>
  <span>logo subtitle</span>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="content-column">
  <main>
    <article>
      Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia. Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia.
      Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia.…
      Quo consequatur dolores facilis fugiat. Maxime non quam eos nisi voluptatem autem minus autem. Consectetur aut molestiae asperiores at impedit. Quam doloribus ut et impedit hic veritatis quia.…
    </article>
  </main>
</div>
<footer>
  2023
</footer>
```